# Event-driven programming in Java wit REST API

Tags: java, rest, events, event-driven

Sorry if this is a very general question or if I don't sound like I know what I'm talking about since I am not 100% sure on how to phrase this question.

I am trying to run a Java program whenever there is a change in the response body of a REST request. My questions are:

1. Is this possible.
2. If it's possible, what's the best way to go about doing this.

Sorry again if this is a stupid question or doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Are you constantly making Rest requests with Java? Then its possible just remember the last body and compare it. If you're talking about frontend then you probably need to use WebSocket.

Comment: You'll need to poll the REST endpoint, unless whatever you're talking to allows you to register a webhook which it will call when something changes.

Comment: @tgdavies that sounds like what I want to do. I have a program that every minute makes a REST API call to the YouTube and Twitch API. I still have more research to do but does anyone know if either of these services offers webhooks, or something similar so I don’t have to make a call every minute? Thanks for the help so far.